# PHP text-field paragraphs

Tags: php, textfield

Is it possible to have paragraphs in "Text-field PHP" i.e content typed in and submitted as paragraphs using shift-enter, and then display in their respective paragraphs in the post....

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Hi the script is textfield rather than text area.

Also it is smarty php

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is your PHP code?

Comment: Hi the script is textfield rather than text area.

Also it is smarty php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//retrieve the textarea value, assuming the form has a textarea named "textfield"
$text = $_REQUEST['textfield'];

//sanitize the text for showing it to the user
$sanitized_text = html_entities($text);

//replacing the new lines from text to <br>
$final_text = nl2br($sanitized_text);

//showing the text to the user, with "paragraphs"
echo '<p>'.$final_text.'</p>';
?>
```

Comment: Hi no, it isnt a text area, this is the issue, it is text fields